How to substitute each regex pattern with a corresponding item from a list
I have a string that I want to do regex substitutions on:
string = 'ptn, ptn; ptn + ptn'

And a list of strings:
array = ['ptn_sub1', 'ptn_sub2', '2', '2']

I want to replace each appearance of the regex pattern 'ptn' with a corresponding item from array.
Desired result:
'ptn_sub1, ptn_sub2; 2 + 2'
I tried using re.finditer to iterate through the matches and substitute each time, but this caused the new string to get mangled since the length of the string changes with each iteration.
import re

matches = re.finditer(r'ptn', string)
new_string = string
for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    span = match.span()
    new_string = new_string[:span[0]] + array[i] + new_string[span[1]:]

Mangled output: 'ptn_sptn_s2, ptn2tn + ptn'
How can I do these substitutions correctly?

re.sub can take a lambda in place of a string as the second parameter. You may be able to use that ability.

What's the relationship of ptn and 2? What's , and ; in ptn, ptn; ptn + ptn?

As stated, one just have to use the "callback" form of re.sub - but it is actually simple enough:
import re
string = 'ptn, ptn; ptn + ptn'
array = ['ptn_sub1', 'ptn_sub2', '2', '2']

array_iter = iter(array)
result = re.sub("ptn", lambda m: next(array_iter), string)



Did you intend for array_iter to be aa, or vice versa?

sorry for that - I normally use these short names (like aa)  when testing stuff in the repl.

Python's re.sub allows one to pass a function that is called on each match. Since your replacement is determined purely by the number of matches found up to that point you can simply keep track of which values have been substituted.
import re

def positional_replacement(array):
    i = 0
    def _inner(match):
        nonlocal i
        try:
            result = array[i]
        except IndexError as e:
            raise IndexError('number of matches exceeds the replacement array') from e
        i += 1
        return result
    return _inner

string = 'ptn, ptn; ptn + ptn'
array = ['ptn_sub1', 'ptn_sub2', '2', '2']

new_string = re.sub(r'ptn', positional_replacement(array), string)
print(new_string) # ptn_sub1, ptn_sub2; 2 + 2

The try/except is there to provide you with a sensible exception if the inputted string exceeds the length of your replacement array.

additionally if you want to work with objects that do not support indexing (like the Python list does) you can update the function to return a generator coroutine. You will have to check for a StopIteration error around the re.sub if you want to handle mismatched numbers of detected patterns vs array length.
import re

def positional_replacer(array):
    def _inner():
        match = yield
        for a in array:
            match = yield a

    gi = _inner()
    next(gi)
    return gi.send

string = 'ptn, ptn; ptn + ptn'
array = ['ptn_sub1', 'ptn_sub2', '2', '2']

new_string = re.sub(r'ptn', positional_replacer(array), string)
print(new_string) # ptn_sub1, ptn_sub2; 2 + 2


yes, these work - but the feeling of "more than what is needed" overcame me - one can just create an iterator to fetch the list values in order (check my answer).
Anyway, I found your usage of returning a generator's .send method great!

That's a fair point, I was aiming to keep the construction of the iterator and its advancement tucked into a single entry point.

Python has other ways to substitute a list of values into several places in a string. If you don't mind changing your syntax, you could do it like this:
>>> "%s, %s: %s + %s" % ('ptn_sub1', 'ptn_sub2', '2', '2')
'ptn_sub1, ptn_sub2: 2 + 2'

Or like this:
>>> array = ['ptn_sub1', 'ptn_sub2', '2', '2']
>>> "{}, {}: {} + {}".format(*array)
'ptn_sub1, ptn_sub2: 2 + 2'

If you do mind changing the syntax, you can still leverage the same method:
>>> string = 'ptn, ptn; ptn + ptn'
>>> array = ['ptn_sub1', 'ptn_sub2', '2', '2']
>>> re.sub(r"\bptn\b", "{}", string).format(*array)
'ptn_sub1, ptn_sub2; 2 + 2'

